# InputStreamReader is not reading č ž š characters

Tags: java, android, text, bufferedreader

I'm working on a project, but when I am reading from file it can't read some characters (like `č` , `ž` , `š`, etc.) I dont know what am I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
try {
    reader = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("koce_podatki.txt"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
for(int i=-1;i<position;i++){
    try {
        temp = "" + br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

try {
    reader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the charset of the file in the constructor of InputStreamReader.

Comment: You need to know which encoding / charset your text editor uses and than use the same while reading the file in java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is one of encoding. Files only store bytes.

There are many ways to map bytes to characters (those ways are called encoding).

When you read from a text file, you must *know* and *specify* which encoding to use.

If you *don't* specify the encoding in Java, the platform default encoding will be used, which *may or may not* be what you want.

In your case it is **not** what you want. To fix this, find out the correct encoding and specify it in [the `InputStreamReader` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29).

A common encoding to try would be UTF-8. If you told us what you see instead of those characters, we could help you guess the correct encoding.

Comment: Writing to a file is called Encoding the text, reading, is called Decoding. The encoder and decoder should use the same protocol.

Comment: For Šimůnek   StandardCharsets.UTF_8 is printing Šim?nek . I am trying to figure out which charset should be used for covering everything.

Comment: @Chetanacharekar: the fact that the first non-ASCII character is printed correctly strongly indicates that UTF-8 is in fact the correct encoding in this case, but that something happens during output. I.e. whatever channel you use to print the result isn't able to encode the ů correctly.

Comment: StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(message,"UTF-8"); solved my issue for http post. By default its not UTF-8 and some characters were missing.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
try {
    reader = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("koce_podatki.txt"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

    while( (s = in.readLine()) != null) {


    String UTF8Str = new String(s.getBytes(),"UTF-8"));
    temp=""+UTF8Str;

    }
```

Comment: No! No! No! don't do it this way! Converting a `String` to "fix" the encoding will work in *some* cases, but in general, it's too late at that point. It's **much better** to use the correct encoding to read the data in the first place!